# Parse DataType from String input

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
DataType = {
   Object: 'OBJECT',
   Number: 'NUMBER',
   String: 'STRING',
   Array: 'ARRAY',
   Date: 'DATE',
}
const data = ['1', 'hello', '[]', '{key: [value]}', '`2020-10-08`'];

function funct(data: string): DataType {
    if(??) {
        return DataType.Object
    } else if(??) {
        return DataType.Number
    } else if(??) {
        return DataType.Array
    } else if (??) {
        return DataType.Date
    }
    return DataType.String
}

data.map((d) => console.log(funct(data)));
// Number, String, Array, Object, Data
```

I'm trying to get the DataType(?) from string input value.

---

I've tried this but it's failing on my tests.

```js
function funct(num) {
  if (/^-?[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?$/.test(num)) {
    return typeof 1;
  } else if (/^[\"'`].*[\"'`]$/) {
    return typeof 'string';
  } else if (/^\[.*\]$/) {
    return typeof []
  } else if (/^\{.*\}$/) {
    return typeof {}
  }

}

console.log('number', funct('1'));
console.log('number', funct('123'));
console.log('string', funct('as2d'));
console.log('string', funct('2s2d'));
console.log('Object', funct('{}')); // returning string :(
console.log('Array', funct('[]')); //returning string :(
console.log('Array', funct('["d", "f"]')); //returning string :(
```

Comment: What is `DataType`? You would have to make rules about how you define those data types and what patterns the strings must follow to belong to those types. For instance, `'hello'`, if passed to `JSON.parse()` would throw an error, because the value is not surrounded by double quotes. `'"hello"'`, however, would be parsed fine, but the rules for JSON are spelled out quite explicitly.

Comment: Looks like they are all strings to me. You are going to write methods that convert it to a number, a date, etc and check to see if it is valid. There is no easy way to do it.

Comment: If all elements inside `data` are strings, how do you discriminate whether `funct(data[0])` should return `Number` or `String`? Or if `'[1]'` is an `Array` or a `String`? Should a string that _can_ be parsed into a something else should always be considered that "something else"?

Comment: Note that DataType uses reserved keywords

Comment: I just edited the question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm not clear on.

Comment: I have an input string and I need to find the type of data based on that

Comment: I think what @DerekPollard means is **why** do you need to do this? If you give more context, you'll get a much better answer.

Comment: I need to show the different results based on the type of the toString() value

Comment: What source are you getting the data from? What do you need to do with it?

Comment: I have operators I need to show. For example, when input is `1`, the operator should't be 'is `greater than`

Comment: I'm getting the data from api. it's often '1' or '`['hi', 'q']`' or 'any string '. I need to show the list of operators based on that

Comment: Then use JSON.parse();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223418/discussion-between-alexh-and-hellofanengineer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you need to detect the types of strings for, but depending on your circumstances you **may** be able to:

1. Use `JSON.parse`. If you're getting data from a server, this is the way to go. Note that you should not parse the string. Instead, parse the *entire response* from the server.
2. Misuse `eval()`. **Don't do this!** It's an option, but the worst one.
3. Regex. It *might* work, but definitely not optimal.

Now that I know the situation, **using `JSON.parse()` is the best option.**

Comment: `JSON.parse` would fail on all the provided data examples except for `[]`

Comment: Not if you parse the whole response. Is the server response JSON?

Comment: Could you check my post again? I added my code

Comment: your regex is not working on my end

Comment: I don't recommend you use the regex.

Comment: Could you add an example ?

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223418/discussion-between-alexh-and-hellofanengineer). I added one there